# Sqitch deploy of stored procedure with ampersand in code causes failure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure, ampersand, sqitch

The Sqitch deploy fails on a stored procedure script that is for snowflake and contains JavaScript code for the stored procedure which has a double ampersand (`&&`) in an IF...THEN conditional block. Sqitch thinks it is a variable and fails as far as I can tell.

Please advise how to treat ampersands (`&`) in comments or in the code of a stored procedure to get sqitch to ignore the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Snowflake docs:

> To use an ampersand sign without using substitution, escape the ampersand sign with a second ampersand sign: `&&variable`

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html

AFAIK, sqitch doesn't support variables, other than the ones native to the database:

https://groups.google.com/g/sqitch-users/c/zYuEYT44OgM/m/WglAw5eDCAAJ